# How do I recognize games that give +1 to my library?

Tags: steam

As you may see from the title, my question is "*What counts as a game on steam?*" or as edited by **NoneOfYourBuisness**: "*How do I recognize games that give +1 to my library?*"

Do Free-to-play games count as well? And if so, what do you need to do to make it count do you have to play it or could you install it then uninstall it without playing it?

Also, I did find a similar question, but it did not answer my leadup question.

Thank you!

Comment: OP has a point, not all games do give +1 for the badge/library count.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness that is my point I am wondering what do I have to do do give me that +1. To play the game or to install it etc.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Is there a difference between the amount of games listed in your library and the count in the dropdown menu?

Comment: The amount of games also include F2P games. Anything you get in the store is regarded as a game, regardless if it is a game or not. The only exceptions are music/Sound Tracks and programs that are regarded as software.

Comment: @3ventic I don't think there is a difference, but for instance when you play a game and remove it it removes the +1.

Comment: When you uninnstall a game you payed, it will stay in the library. F2P games will disappear

Comment: So does that mean @AhkamNihardeen that you can't make a F2P game 'stay' in your library without it being installed?

Comment: Yes. When you get a F2P game, it will start installing and get in your library. If you uninstall the F2P game, it gets removed from your library. The only way to keep it without being installed is to get the game, and while it is installing pause the installation

Comment: And even if you play it for X hours and uninstall it it will -1?

Comment: Yes @Sebie, that is true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17805/discussion-between-ahkam-nihardeen-and-sebie).

Comment: Ok, will continue in chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of games also include F2P games. Anything you get in the store is regarded as a game, regardless if it is a game or not. The only exceptions are music/Sound Tracks and programs that are regarded as software.

---

When you uninstall a game you payed for, it will stay in the library. F2P games will disappear

---

The only way to keep it without being installed is to get the game, and while it is installing pause the installation

Comment: No problems @Sebie :D